# Bootstrap SASS exchange columns on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, multiple-columns

I would like to know how to exchange column in Bootstrap SASS ? I would like to exchange order of columns between desktop and mobile's version.

I try this :

```
first {
   @include make-sm-column(5);
   @include make-xs-column-push(5);
}
second {
   @include make-sm-column(7);
   @include make-xs-column-pull(7);
}
```

[image]